# Pandas сортировка

Tags: python, pandas

Есть DataFrame:

```
                    <LAST>  <VOL>
datetime        
2019-10-28 10:00:00 141990     1
2019-10-28 10:00:00 141990     1
2019-10-28 10:01:00 141960     1
2019-10-28 10:01:02 141970     2
2019-10-28 10:00:00 141910     1
2019-10-28 10:02:00 141930     1
2019-10-28 10:03:00 141910     2
2019-10-28 10:03:10 141950     1
2019-10-28 10:04:05 141970     2
2019-10-28 10:05:00 141910     2
```

Группирую следующим образом:

```
grouped_data = (volume.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='datetime', freq='60min'), '<LAST>'])
                .agg({'<VOL>' : sum}))
```

Выводит:

```
                    <LAST>  <VOL>
datetime        
2019-10-28 10:00:00 141910     5
                    141930     1
                    141950     1
                    141960     1
                    141970     4
                    141990     2
```

Возможно ли вывести данные без сортировки? Таким образом?

```
                    <LAST>  <VOL>
datetime        
2019-10-28 10:00:00 141990     2
                    141960     1
                    141970     4
                    141910     5
                    141930     1
                    141950     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У groupby есть опциональный параметр sort. По умолчанию индекс сортируется, если сказать False, то значения останутся в порядке появления

```
grouped_data = (volume \
        .groupby([pd.Grouper(level='datetime', freq='60min'), '<LAST>'], sort=False) \
        .agg({'<VOL>' : sum}))

                            <VOL>
datetime            <LAST>       
2019-10-28 10:00:00 141990      2
                    141960      1
                    141970      4
                    141910      5
                    141930      1
                    141950      1
```